# Accessing Big Query Table from VM throwing Invalid Table Name error

Tags: google-bigquery, virtual-machine, service-accounts, google-iam

I have created a bigquery dataset and table like my-test-project-388514.babanames.all-baby-names. Added the Service Account With BigQuery Admin Role both in Dataset Level and Table Level. After that I have created one VM with that service account selected. Also the service account is having IAM BigQuery Admin Role in the IAM section.

With all these, when I am issuing the below command from VM SSH window, it is throwing me the error.

Command: `bq query 'SELECT * FROM` my-test-project-388514.babanames.all-baby-names `LIMIT 1000'`

Error:

```
There is no apilog flag so non-critical logging is disabled.
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job 'my-test-
project-388514:bqjob_r22055e354882c867_00000188a14dffc8_1': Invalid table name: `my-test-
project-388514.babanames.all-baby-names`
[Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)].
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: As in the error message, you need to use standard SQL. Would you try it again with `--nouse_legacy_sql` option like `bq query --nouse_legacy_sql ...`  ?

Comment: Thank you @Jaytiger. Your solution worked. But any idea why I need to use standard SQL to access the table?

Comment: [This](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql) might be helpful.  And you can access the table with legacy SQL, but need to use different syntax in legacy SQL to reference table.  In your case, it will be  `[my-test-project-388514:babanames.all-baby-names]`